# How to filter all lowercase letters from a string having special characters?

Tags: javascript, string

The input string is - `"my&friend&Paul has heavy hats! &"`.

And I want to get rid of everything except lowercase letters like:
`"myfriendaulhasheavyhats"`

I split it and applied the `toLowerCase()` method, but it doesn't work with special characters. Need some help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace all none a-z characters by an empty string

```
"my&friend&Paul has heavy hats! &".replace(/[^a-z]/g, "");
```

Comment: you dont need the `+`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace` function as follows:

```js
let str = "my&friend&Paul has heavy hats! &";
str = str.replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `regex` with `join`

```js
let str = "my&friend&Paul has heavy hats! &";

console.log(str.match(/[a-z]/g).join(""))
```